# initialization of a reference in a dynamically allocated structure

Tags: c++

Anyone knows how to initialize a reference in a dynamically allocated structure?
or why this doesnt work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

class A
{

};

struct S
{
    A& a;
};

int main()
{
    A a;

    S* s=new S;
    s->a=a;

    printf("a addr:%p\n", &a);
    printf("s->a addr:%p\n", &(s->a));
delete s;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
a addr:0x7fff95b65aaf
s->a addr:(nil)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize reference members within the initializer list of a constructor. Even the body of the constructor is too late, because the member has already been initialized, and can't be changed.

In your code, you are using the (compiler-provided) default constructor, and then trying to set the reference after the object has been constructed.

Try this:

```
struct S
{
    S(A& a_) : a(a_){} 
    A& a;
};

int main()
{
    A a;

    S* s=new S(a);
...
```

Comment: but then even if I overload a contructor how do I use it before the object gets contructed?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You can't use an object before it gets constructed.

Comment: oh you mean the constructor of the structure?

Comment: Yes. To initialize a member of a class or structure, where the member is a reference, it has to be initialized in the initializer list of a constructor. Even within the body of the constructor is too late.

Comment: sorry for all the comments I just found out how to do it thx :)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because you are trying to *assign* something to a reference member (which, of course, does not affect the reference itself, but rather the referenced object). You are not *initializing* the reference in your code. References can only be initialized at the very moment they are "born", their initialization cannot be postponed for later.

When you do `new S`, you are asking the compiler to use the compiler-generated default constructor for `S`. The default constructor for `S` cannot be generated, since the compiler does not know how to initialize reference member `a`. References in C++ cannot be left uninitialized, they cannot be default-initialized, and they value-initialized. Specific initializer always has to be supplied explicitly.

Unfortunately in C++89/C++03 there's no way to do that for a dynamically allocated `struct S` (as defined in your code). You have to provide your own constructor for this.

In C++11 you can use uniform initailization syntax

```
S *s = new S { a };
```

which will attach the `S::a` member of newly allocated object to `a`.